# NGINX and Node.js Caching returning the same results on all subfolders

Tags: nginx, proxy, cache, node.js

We use NGINX to proxy a connection to a Node.js instance running on the same server.  Without caching turned on for that location, at one level (i.e. /v1/streams/) it returns a 2MB json file.  If an ID is added to the URL (i.e. /v1/streams/98souisdlfj87) only a very small portion of that 2MB json file is returned.

If we add caching by adding a new location pointing to /v1/streams, all requests return the 2MB json file, regardless of the folder depth.

Here are the relevant portions of my my configs.

```
    http    {
            proxy_cache_path /var/lib/nginx/cache levels=1:2
                     keys_zone=streams:10m
                     max_size=1g inactive=10h;
            proxy_cache_key "$request_uri";

            proxy_headers_hash_max_size 8192;
            proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 256;
            proxy_ignore_headers "Set-Cookie";
    }


    server {
            location /v1/ {
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5001/;
                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header XNginX-Proxy true;
                    proxy_redirect off;
                    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            }
            location /v1/streams {
                    proxy_cache streams;
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5001/streams/;
                    add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
                    proxy_cache_valid 200 204 302 1d;
                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header XNginX-Proxy true;
                    proxy_redirect off;
                    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.   I was missing the trailing slash on the location.

`location /v1/streams/ {`

Now it works.